# Styling a cfcontent which produced an excel sheet with an external stylesheet

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to incorporate a stylesheet to a `cfcontent` tag that will produce an Excel spreadsheet as shown below. However, the stylesheet is always ignored even when it is linked with an explicit reference. What would ensure that the Excel spreadsheet would incorporate the stylesheet?

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="Yes">
<cfsavecontent variable="sTest">
    <cfoutput>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="www.somesite.com/bootstrap/another.css" media="all">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssBootstrap/css/another.css" media="all">
        </head>
        <body>     
        <cfinclude template="../Reports/reportexportedasEXcel.cfm">
        </body>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=filename#DateFormat(now(),"mmdd")#-#TimeFormat(Now(),"HHMMSS")#.xls">  
<cfoutput>
    <html>      
    </head>
    <body>
        #sTest#
    </body>
    </html>
</cfoutput> 
</cfcontent>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you trying to style an Excel spreadsheet with CSS files?  You can't do that.  CSS is for the web (HTML). Formatting for Excel spreadsheets needs to be done using the tools within Excel. There is some limited formatting that can be applied to a spreadsheet using the Apache POI that comes with Adobe ColdFusion. You can start by reading the docs about the spreadsheet formatting functions SpreadsheetFormatxxxxx - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1fb12-7fd6.html

Comment: @Miguel-F Excel has the ability to render HTML files, and an old hack is to rename an HTML file .xls to force Excel to open it. The app I maintain has used this hack quite a bit, though at some point I'd like to update it to all legitimate xls and xlsx files. I do think JqueryHelp will have a lot more issues ahead with how the code is currently set up.

Comment: Twillen, What other issues do you see ?

Comment: Miguel, i am trying to style the excel spreadsheet with a bootstrap.css. Inline styling on each table data and table header seems to work but an external stylesheet renders nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Include the protocol in the link to the style sheet.  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.somesite.com/bootstrap/another.css" media="all">`

Another option would be to include the style sheet content into the xls file.

```
<cfset cssFilePath = getDirectoryFromPath(gettemplatePath()) & "../cssBootstrap/css/another.css" />
<cfset cssContent = fileRead(cssFilePath) />
</cfscript>
<html>
    <cfoutput>
        <head>
            <style>#cssContent#</style>
        </head>
    </cfoutput>
```

Comment: reading it with cfscript and having it as an output  still ignores the stylesheet, i might be fighting a losing battle, a bad cliche but it could be true.Also i already had the explicit call for the stylesheet so i am not exactly sure on what do you mean by include the "protocol" ?

Comment: `http://` is the protocol of the url, at lest in your question the protocol was excluded. The main issues I see with your html xls file is the bootstrap css file. I don't know the extent of the Excels ability to render html, and modern css. With a layout designed around Bootstrap, targeting Excel may be as fun as targeting IE 6.

Comment: I agree that you are fighting a losing battle. Just out of curiousity, if you ignore all the styling stuff and simply use html to create a file with a .xls extension, does exel open it nicely?